# How to prevent error when customising Django model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am using djoser for my rest api authentication

When I try to add phone number functionality to the model the following Error occurs:

```
    OperationalError at /api/users/
no such table: api_user
```

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True,blank=False,null=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name'
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'username',
    ]

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer,UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone'
        )
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'

##  Djoser 
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD':'email',

    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create':'api.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'api.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
    },
}
```

How would I fix this error.

Also, is there a way to remove the username from models? I only want email for authentication.

Comment: You need to run makemigrations and migrate to create the database tables for your model

Comment: i have done it. but still not working.

Comment: Is there an existing migrations folder in the api app? You need to run “makemigrations api” to create an initial migration for the app if not

Comment: it worked.Thanx

Comment: if i dont want to use useranme field what should i do.i neglected username from fields but it throws an error,create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Comment: Add “username = None” to your user model if you want to remove the username field. You may need to customise your user manager to remove references to the field

Comment: i have changed to username=None but still dont works

Comment: What doesn’t work? Maybe this is for another question

Comment: ok , i will post the question